# Is it possible to install iOS6 SDK on Xcode 6-beta?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, beta

I noticed that there are no preview or simulator for iOS6 in Xcode 6-beta, so I was wondering is there any way that I could add it manually ?

Comment: usually Apple only supports current version -1 ... so iOS8 and iOS7 ... if you need iOS6 stick to Xcode 5

Comment: The problem is that Xcode 6 broke Xcode 5's iOS 6 simulator for me.

Comment: Same problem for me, in Xcode 5 I keep getting an error and a black screen in the IOS6 simulator (IOS7 is ok). I tried to reset the simulator and delete the cache files but without effect...

Comment: The iOS6 simulator works for me if I xcode-select -s path_to_xcode5

Comment: Xcode 6 GM available, and still no IOS6.

Anyone are using ios6 with this GM.  If yes, can you please confirm the steps?

Thanks, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

No.

Apple only support iOS7 and iOS8, and they're strict with that.  As a result, only iOS7/8 simulators are available in Xcode 6.

If you want to run on an older simulator, you need to develop on an older version of XCode.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. But: you can still test on a iOS 6 device from Xcode 6. I keep an old iPhone 4 for this (look at eBay).

EDIT: there is another way - install Xcode 5 on a virtual machine (e.g. VMWare Fusion) running Mavericks.

Answer (score 2):

iOS6 simulator is available in Xcode5

Comment: Why did people mark this answer down? I just marked it up from –4 to –3. Strictly speaking, it doesn't answer the question (the answer being "no") but it does give a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

No, the earliest SDK you can get for Xcode 6 is 7.1. By default, the iOS 7 simulator is not installed but you can install it by going to preferences, then to downloads and installing it from there.

To run iOS 6 applications, try googling around for an earlier Xcode version (late versions of 4) and these should have the simulator!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, I have iOS 7.0 in my iOS Simulator