# How can I install Xcode 6 along side Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, installation, beta, versions

I was wondering if there is a way that I could install Xcode 6 along side Xcode 5. I've seen people say you could but they haven't really explained why. Can someone help to explain why? Also, how would you uninstall it if I wished to in the future?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simple. The Xcode 6 beta is named `Xcode6-beta.app` and you drag install it into `/Applications`. The GM version of Xcode is called `Xcode.app`. If you need to switch the command line tools you use `xcode-select`. Nothing has changed here. It's the same as it's been. When you want to "uninstall" it, drag it to the trash. It's that simple.

Comment: or more precisely for command line tools: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app

Comment: How can I achieve this if I download Xcode via Mac App Store?

Comment: I've not specifically tried this, but I have a few thoughts: The App Store is likely to want its idea of the "current" Xcode to be named "Xcode.app", but it seems plausible that you could rename old ones to "Xcode-VERSION.app" or something. If you wanted to be extra sure, you could zip the old one before updating through the app store to keep the App Store from finding and deleting the old one.

Comment: Time has passed significantly, but I thank you for showing me that. At the time I didn't fully understand Xcode, but have become familiar since.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the default command line tools via GUI, if you prefer: XCode > Preferences > Locations, Dropdown "Command Line Tools"...

Answer (score 0):

Attention, you can effectively install Xcode 6 and keep Xcode 5 but this is not working perfectly fine. For example this broke my Xcode 5 IOS6 simulators and I am now unable to run my apps on this old ios version [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038286/is-it-possible-to-install-ios6-sdk-on-xcode-6-beta)

I didn't find any solution for now and there may be others problems, so be aware this operation is not without risks

Answer (score 0):

You might be far better off creating a partition with OSX Yosemite and installing Beta Software there. I moved over my apps to the Yosemite partition and only the Xcode 6 Beta 4 ran them - yeah!

Here is where I will work with untested software.

Good luck!