# Can we install iOS 6 simulator in XCODE 6.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios-simulator, xcode6

I updated my **XCODE** version to **6.0.1** from **5.1.1** but when i try to install **iOS simulator 6** , i cant find it in **XCODE -> Preferences -> Downloads** option ...

My project needs iOS 6 environment

Can anyone please suggest a way to install it or get back to older version.

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install iOS6 SDK on Xcode 6-beta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038286/is-it-possible-to-install-ios6-sdk-on-xcode-6-beta)

Comment: hi my question is about ios simulator 6 and returning back to xcode 5, its not the duplicate of that you mentioned and i want to test in ios6 while xcode 6 installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run app in iOS 6 Simulator in Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631551/run-app-in-ios-6-simulator-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't install that simulator in Xcode 6.0.1. You can download Xcode 5.1.1 from the iOS Developer Center: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

If that link doesn't work login to the dev center and under the downloads section click "Looking for an older version of Xcode?"

[image]

In the search box type "Xcode 5.1.1" and filter your Categories to Developer Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 6 contains CoreSimulator.  CoreSimulator supports the iOS 7.0 and later simulator runtimes.

The iOS 7.0 simulator runtime is not supported on OS X Yosemite.

If you are on OS X Mavericks, you can install 7.0 or later.

If you are on OS X Yosemite, you can install 7.1 or later.

If you need the iOS 6 simulator runtime, you should install Xcode 5.1 (on Mavericks) and use it for testing your projects in the iOS 6 runtime.  You can install both versions of Xcode simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. 
With Xcode 5.1 on Yosemite, would it be possible to run iOS 6 simulator ? or is it the same for 7.0 simulator on Yosemite : no support ?
Thanks

Comment: Xcode 5.1 is not supported on Yosemite.  Even if you managed to install it and try to run the 6.1 simulator, it will not work on Yosemite due to incompatibilities with the host runtime.